# How do I read the value of a pointer to a slice using reflect?

Tags: pointers, go, slice, reflect

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {

    type tu struct {
        N int
    }

    type t struct {
        ARRAY []tu
        NESTED *tu
        NESTED_ARRAY []*tu
    }

    var n = t{[]tu{{4}}, &tu{5}, []*tu{{6}}}

    //print value
    fmt.Printf("value2: %v\n", reflect.ValueOf(&n).Elem().Field(1).Slice(0, 1))
    fmt.Printf("value3: %v\n", reflect.ValueOf(&n).Elem().Field(2).Elem().Field(0))
    fmt.Printf("value4: %v\n", reflect.ValueOf(&n).Elem().Field(3).Slice(0, 1).Elem().Field(0))

    return
}
```

I'm trying to access the value of a slice pointer using reflection.

`reflect.ValueOf(&n).Elem().Field(3).Slice(0, 1).Elem().Field(0)` should work but it doesn't.

How should I go around doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field index starts with `0`, not `1`. So decrease all indices by 1.

And in your last example the [`Value.Slice()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Slice) call returns a slice, not a pointer (not an element of the slice, but a subslice). If you need an element, call [`Value.Index()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Index) on that, then you can call [`Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem) and [`Field()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Field):

```
fmt.Printf("value2: %v\n", reflect.ValueOf(&n).Elem().Field(0).Slice(0, 1))
fmt.Printf("value3: %v\n", reflect.ValueOf(&n).Elem().Field(1).Elem().Field(0))
fmt.Printf("value4: %v\n", reflect.ValueOf(&n).Elem().Field(2).Slice(0, 1).Index(0).Elem().Field(0))
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eUIz9SLKhYj)):

```
value2: [{4}]
value3: 5
value4: 6
```

Also note that the [`Value.Slice()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Slice) method is equivalent to a slicing expression. If you need an element, just call `Value.Index()`, you don't need the `Slice()` method:

```
fmt.Printf("value2: %v\n", reflect.ValueOf(&n).Elem().Field(0).Index(0))
fmt.Printf("value3: %v\n", reflect.ValueOf(&n).Elem().Field(1).Elem().Field(0))
fmt.Printf("value4: %v\n", reflect.ValueOf(&n).Elem().Field(2).Index(0).Elem().Field(0))
```

This will output (try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/xotj9UgwL4e)):

```
value2: {4}
value3: 5
value4: 6
```